# What's acceptable practice for Stack Overflow code review for several source files, GitHub?

Tags: discussion, code, github, code-review-se

I have some code that I want to put on Stack Overflow for a code review. What is the best way to handle multiple files? Should I just ask a question and put a link to a public [GitHub](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GitHub) repository? What do people usually do in this case?

Comment: This might fit better here - http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: Stack Overflow and Code Review are not the same thing. Which one are you talking about?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Stack Overflow is better suited for practical programming questions about specific issues. Try [CodeReview.StackExchange.com](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) for code reviews. Be sure to read their [FAQ](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) though. For one, I think it's preferred or even required to put your code (the relevant bits) in the question to make it stand on itself, as well as to prevent [link rot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link_rot). To quote the relevant bits from their FAQ:

> **What topics can I ask about here?**
>   Code Review Stack Exchange is for sharing code from projects you are working on for peer review.
>
> **Make sure you include your code in your question**
>   This site is for code reviews, which are hard to do when the code is behind a link somewhere out there on the internet. If you want a code review, you must post the relevant snippets of code in your question. It is fine to post a "see more" link (though, do be careful — very few reviewers will be willing to click through and read thousands of lines of your code), but the most important parts of the code must be placed directly in the question.

Comment: Yes.... review of the entire source is not practical.  Review of a subset, or specific methods or classes are more appropriate.